# Pandoc .docx to .md with math and images

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to export .docx file to a .md file with math and images. However, only the image is present on the new file, but not the math in mathjax. Any idea how to solve this?

The code I use is: `pandoc --extract-media=.-s file.docx -t markdown -o file.md`

Comment: Can you provide a small example, including input, actual output, and expected output? Otherwise we'd have to guess all that, making it difficult to help.

Comment: also make sure to use the newest pandoc version...